# Hive couldn't find file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to add a file in hive:

```
hive> add FILE '/opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py';
'/opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py' does not exist
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: '/opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py' does not exist
```

but the file does exist in the folder:

```
[root@localhost ml-100k]# ls -l /opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py 
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root 278 Jun 17 10:10 /opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py
```

Why the first add query in Hive says the file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `add FILE /opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py;`

remove the quotes from the path specified in `add FILE '/opt/hadoop/weekday_mapper.py';`

Comment: Thank you. I guess you are right, but I'll open another thread for another new issue.

Comment: @mdivk okay. I see only tat issue.